# How to fix Conflicting distribution for my local apt repo?

Tags: repository, apt

I was trying to make an apt repo. I have this deb which is not architecture dependant and this is the structure of my repo:

```
.
├── dists
│   └── testing
│       ├── InRelease
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── Packages
│       │   └── Packages.gz
│       ├── Release
│       └── Release.gpg
├── KEY.gpg
└── pool
    └── testing
        └── main
            └── s
                └── savcli
                    └── savcli_0.0.1_all.deb
```

I add `deb <uri-to-repo> testing main` to my sources.list. I also add the key, But when I `apt update` I get these errors:

```
W: Conflicting distribution: <uri-to-repo> testing InRelease (expected testing but got )
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository '<uri-to-repo> testing InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository '<uri-to-repo> testing InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)
```

I'm not sure what's wrong and how I can fix this. I don't want to make a flat repo and add `[trusted=yes]`. So what have I done wrong?

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing configuration details in the release and in release files some examples of how a Release File should look like are. You can see more examples here https://lists.debian.org/debian-mentors/2006/04/msg00294.html and `Configuring reprepro` https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/SetupWithReprepro#Generating_OpenPGP_keys

I used apt-ftparchive to genereate my release file and so I used the following CLI command

```bash
apt-ftparchive \
      -o APT::FTPArchive::Release::Origin="my app" \
      -o APT::FTPArchive::Release::Label="my app" \
      -o APT::FTPArchive::Release::Architectures="arm64" \
      -o APT::FTPArchive::Release::Components="main" \
      -o APT::FTPArchive::Release::Description="Apt repository for my app" \
      -o APT::FTPArchive::Release::Codename="stable" \
      -o APT::FTPArchive::Release::Suite="main" \
      release ./dists/stable/ > ./dists/stable/Release
```

The Release File output will look somthing similar too

```
Architectures: arm64
Codename: stable
Components: main
Date: Tue, 27 Dec 2022 14:53:28 +0000
Description: Apt repository for my app
Label: My App
Origin: My App
Suite: main
MD5Sum:
 f948e3b9ecc3ee1bb89490eec5a897e8              197 Release
 50101e65a457f7adfdb11be49f36e2e4              600 main/binary-arm64/Packages
 ff153fcc8b9f9f49d0c917afd97bff72              454 main/binary-arm64/Packages.gz
SHA1:
 3f9bdf152d1060d28faef385f22e2b3a39bdba95              197 Release
 5648155184dabe68f8b01f09d4c70afee215f289              600 main/binary-arm64/Packages
 7582505ccae55b2d624f8d3ae42ec5104ddad057              454 main/binary-arm64/Packages.gz
SHA256:
 1abb7494951bbdeb04a5e0fc8124b35144a7d22b16c6716e18a140135328fa82              197 Release
 afbb25d8792a6377c8b63b8fe3754419337eed319cfb546945cecc95d3207f3b              600 main/binary-arm64/Packages
 7cfc6394fc938e0824c82ea15a03dfa1e72c5d344e8d85abeb4d317b0b643fc3              454 main/binary-arm64/Packages.gz
SHA512:
 d8c327407e2eca79a58db5934ebbe617198778fa34b9a506dc6c9ac57f3f680658e8c069f15af58eb75a27596166b6e2ee6991861e05f5346ea503874ab2aa88              197 Release
 e275bdc954cfbf05d525c0a1c94c709411caf84bc5dd8c9e888b78d6108c4d93f7a5b31f42466ed21b740e1e69a14784f79f2815d019faaa8b411f9a30562ea1              600 main/binary-arm64/Packages
 d8ccc972408816d791130076a859249b822c19183b746137ee61d765134ef59ab9e72ce43c9755c11c8540dfb55f7d573796036137f4f8296f35d8cafb79b3b6              454 main/binary-arm64/Packages.gz
```